# How to identify unused secrets in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to rename my k8s `Secrets` and want to check if there are unused `Secrets`. Also I would like to know how many and which `containers` reference a `Secret`.

Is there a easier way to do this than search for the secret names in all deployments?

Comment: Look at this one https://github.com/dtan4/k8s-unused-secret-detector

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks Simon. Based on your answer I created a diff, which shows `secrets` that are not referenced in the containers env section. `Secrets` can also be referenced in:

- `TLS` section of Ingresses
- `Pods` `Volumes` spec, like Simon mentioned
- `ImagePullSecrets` for private repositories
- `CRDs` Custom Resource Definitions

But for me it is enough to find `secrets` that are not referenced in environment variables:

```
diff \
<(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].env[*].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name}' | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq) \
<(kubectl get secrets -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq)
```

**Update 16.04.2018**

I created a more advanced version to find also secrets referenced in `volumes`, `ingress tls` and `imagePullSecrets`. The following snippet will show you all unused `secrets` for the current namespace.

**Caution:** The script does not cover all options where secrets can be referenced (e.g. Custom Resource Definitions).

**Update 15.06.2021**: Added secrets from Pod container spec `envFrom[*].secretRef.name` as secret source

**Update 06.07.2023**: Added secrets that are used as service account tokens

```
envSecrets=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].env[*].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name}' | xargs -n1)
envSecrets2=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].envFrom[*].secretRef.name}' | xargs -n1)
volumeSecrets=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.volumes[*].secret.secretName}' | xargs -n1)
pullSecrets=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.imagePullSecrets[*].name}' | xargs -n1)
tlsSecrets=$(kubectl get ingress -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.tls[*].secretName}' | xargs -n1)
SASecrets=$(kubectl get secrets --field-selector=type=kubernetes.io/service-account-token -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -n1)


diff \
<(echo "$envSecrets\n$envSecrets2\n$volumeSecrets\n$pullSecrets\n$tlsSecrets\n$SASecrets" | sort | uniq) \
<(kubectl get secrets -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq)
```

Comment: you must sort before uniq otherwise it wont be uniq

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I adapted my answer.

Comment: Using bash version 5 I have noticed I'd best skip the `\n` as they don't result in newlines and clutter the diff.

Comment: Also, this misses secrets in initContainers. Other things to consider: deployments and statefulsets scaled to zero and secrets used by other tools like Jenkins.

Comment: Note that secrets may be used by Custom Resources (in my case: a cert-manager Issuer), so this needs to be used with caution.

Comment: You are right @Ulli. I added a hint that this does not cover all possible references.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me. Besides those you specified, I added an extra case for when a deployment includes all values from a secret, rather than only specific ones: `kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].envFrom[*].secretRef.name}' | xargs -n1`

Comment: Thanks @KentMuntheCaspersen. I added this source to my answer.

Comment: I think you need to add `-e` in in echo to make `\n` work.

Comment: I am using macOS. There, it works out of the box. But `-e` might be required for other shells: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189819/279362

Comment: Amazing answer, sweet!

Comment: `sort -u` is often a decent replacement to `sort | uniq` (it might require GNU sort though)

Answer (score 8):

There is no intended way to list unused Secrets because Secrets themselves do not hold reference of usage. One solution would be to parse all Containers/Pods for usage of secrets as mounts and environment variables to match against your list of secrets. `kubectl get` supports [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath/) and makes that pretty easy:

### Retrieve secrets used as mounts

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.volumes[*].secret.secretName}' | xargs -n1 | uniq
```

### Retrieve secrets used as environment variables

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].env[*].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name}' | xargs -n1 | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool which helps finds unused secrets (and other resources)
[kor](https://github.com/yonahd/kor)