# Finding out the Kubernetes object that uses the Kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I want to know the Object(`Deployment/Statefulset/..`) which is using a secret. Is there a way to find this out from a secret? Is there a tool in Kubernetes community to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is nothing built in, but you can use `kubectl` in conjuction with `jq` to figure it out. Here is the example for `deployments`

```
kubectl get deployment -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.spec.template.spec.volumes[]? | .secret.secretName=="<secret name>") | .metadata.name'
```

Comment: That covers the pod spec of a deployment but It's a fairly large matrix of resources/paths to cover references generally

Comment: I wonder if there's a generic way to search the resource tree. I don't think a reference to a secret is a well defined api object

Comment: @Matt I absolutely agree and would be glad to figure it out as well. Meanwhile this is the best I could do till now

Comment: I had a quick look, most adhere to an [ObjectReference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/common-definitions/object-reference/) with "secret" in the name but there are caveats like a projected volume. This would be useful though, if I get a chance I'll try put the list together.

Comment: This other answer has examples for a number of other common resources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412286/3276583

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to show the labels of the Object(Deployment/Statefulset) that matches the labels of the Secret

The Pods for example

`kubectl get pods [pod_name] --show-labels`

or

To get the label of the Secrets

`kubectl describe secrets [secret_name]`

`kubectl get secrets`

Comment: Secrets aren't referenced by labels in workload resources so this isn't guaranteed to link them